# codeigniter site returns 404 error after server move

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I am in the process of moving an existing codeigniter website from a MediaTemple shared server to a Dreamhost VPS server.  I have set up a mirror of the new server to view the site without switching the DNS; you can see it [here](http://www.ornaments.dreamhosters.com/)

I have attempted to switch the DNS, but the problems persisted.

As you can see, it returns a 404 error.  If I remove the htaccess file, the home page will come up, but none of the html pages will work. I think that this has to do with the RewriteCond and RewriteRule statements in the htaccess file.

Here is the htaccess file:

```
AddHandler php-stable .php
php_flag allow_url_fopen on
# php_flag extension_dir=/home/86983/data/lib/php
# php_flag extension=zip.so


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond $1!^(js|css|images|license\.txt|user_guide|admin|phpMyAdmin|uploads|ornaments_sitemap2_25_09\.xml|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|quickscript\.php|paypal_ipn\.php|test\.php|sitedown\.php)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ornaments.com/sitedown\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ornaments\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ornaments.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|backupForPhpMyAdmin|blog|change_page_name\.php|css|favicon\.ico|images|index\.php|js|license\.txt|ornaments_sitemap2_25_09\.xml|paypal_ipn\.php|phpMyAdmin|uploads|quickscript\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|sub-domains|test\.php|testblog\.php|url_checker|user_guide|tinymy\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^s86983\.gridserver\.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule (.*) http://www.s86983\.gridserver.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# 
# RewriteCond $1 !^(blog|index\.php|js|css|images|license\.txt|user_guide|admin|phpMyAdmin|uploads|ornaments_sitemap2_25_09\.xml|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|quickscript\.php|paypal_ipn\.php|test\.php|backupForPhpMyAdmin)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Note:  I did not build this site and am only slightly familiar with codeigniter and PHP in general.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to remove first two lines from your .htacces file

Comment: I removed the first two lines and now get this message when I refresh the page:  "No input file specified. "

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you copy in htaccess this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.c
    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you, I copied this into the htaccess and left everything else the way it was.  I still get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this one by replacing the htaccess file with the one from the openCart part of the site that worked. That file looks like this:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]



### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
#php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
#php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.shop.ornaments.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shop.ornaments.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am not clear on why it worked and what might still be broken that we can't yet see, but so far it looks good.